# Float to String Convert in Udp.write() in esp8266

Tags: esp8266

I want to convert float value to String for send **Udp.Write()**
 method
 and receive another side (esp) with **Udp.read()** 
and 
Copy in the one Variable for use ..

**please** help me
**Thanks for every answer ^__^**

code :

```
void loop () {
    int signal = analogRead (A0) ;
    float Adc = (signal * 3.3) / 4096 ;
    Udp.beginPacket ({192,168,4,1} , 1234) ;
    Udp.write ( " please help me fill this section ") ;
    Udp.endPacket () ;
}
```

---

*i have one more problom . . .*

*and in the other side:*

i want take the**Adc** value from **esp1** and **convert char to float** for **Dac**

(*digital analog converter*) with *MCP4725* ..

** i just need put in float value of Adc in a variable for convertation use ..**

*code*:

**void loop ( ) {**

```
int noBytes = Udp.parsePacket();

String received_command = "";


if ( noBytes ) {

  Udp.read(packetBuffer,noBytes);

  for (int i=1;i<=noBytes;i++){

  received_command += char(packetBuffer[i - 1]);
} 

Serial.print("packaet receive: ");

Serial.println(received_command);


float Adc_value_received = float(received_command); //*helpppp please char-to-float convert*
```

**}**

*thanks from everyone* ^__^

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation for `String`?  https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

Comment: Or even googling it? Normally you find various examples when googling for "Arduino convert X to Y"

Comment: Try something like: `String msg = String(Adc, 3); Udp.write(msg.c_str());`

Comment: **Special thanks to Mikael Patel** .^___^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino String class can be used to convert to a character string.

```
void loop () {
    int signal = analogRead (A0) ;
    float Adc = (signal * 3.3) / 4096 ;
    String msg = String(Adc, 3); 

    Udp.beginPacket ({192,168,4,1}, 1234) ;
    Udp.write(msg.c_str()); 
    Udp.endPacket () ;
}
```